# Set the number of digits after the point in double

Tags: c#, types, double

In c# double type how can i set the number of digits after the point, i need only 4.
thank you.

Comment: inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 4);

Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357855/round-double-in-two-decimal-places-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. [Binary floating point](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/floatingpoint.html) doesn't work like that. You can *format* a double that way (e.g. using `"f4"` as the format string), but if you're dealing with values which have a natural number of *decimal* places, then you should probably be using `decimal` instead. Could you give us more information about what your values represent?

Comment: i m doing an equality between 2 points's x and there values are
5.0000 and 4.999999996
and i need it te be true

Comment: @Bass: If you're only doing an equality test, then nobugz's answer is probably the right way to go. I would still consider whether you want to use decimal instead though - it depends on the kind of values you've got.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the number of digits after the point on the double directly.

You can change the string representation of the double using a format string.

One example would be:

```
string.Format("{0:0.####}", number);
```

Or as Jon Skeet points out:

```
number.ToString("f4")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to compare two floating point numbers to 4 digits in the fraction:

```
  if (Math.Abs(a - b) < 1E-4) {
    // close enough
    //...
  }
```

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure they are equal then it should be Double.epsilon rather than 1e-4. If you want to say they are 'close enough' equal then you're code is fine

Comment: Double.Epsilon cannot work as-is, it is far too small.  A proper epsilon is something like a * 1E-15 but that has to be incremented for errors accumulated by each FP operation.