# Round double in two decimal places in C#?

Tags: c#, double, rounding

I want to round up double value in two decimal places in c# how can i do that?

```
double inputValue = 48.485;
```

after round up

```
inputValue = 48.49;
```

#### Related: [c# - How do I round a decimal value to 2 decimal places (for output on a page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164926/c-sharp-how-do-i-round-a-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-for-output-on-a-pa)

Comment: Take note that you can't represent all floating point values using double and this can [trip you up when rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27323465/542251)

Answer (score 626, accepted):

This works:

```
inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 2);
```

Comment: workaround to trunc float: 
    float myTruncFloat = float.Parse(Math.Round(myFloat, 2).ToString());

Comment: If value is 48.0000. It will not result 48.00.   double inputValue = 48.00;
            inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 2); will result 48 only. Any warkaound ?

Comment: according to the documentation this would round mid point numbers to the nearest even number https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_

Comment: @user1926138 48.00 is not a valid number.

Answer (score 128):

```
Math.Round(inputValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: This is actually what should be used. Most operations in banks etc are done using this method (MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).

Comment: suggesting that banks use doubles is scary dude, don't use approximation values for currency.

Comment: @raggi I'm afraid some (banks) do...
That would explain a lot of stuff

Comment: Yes I believe this was what the movie 'Office Space' was made after - rounding off fractions of cents that nobody would notice. Good point to be careful about when to arbitrarily use rounding.

Comment: And as part of the plot of one of the original Superman movies waaay long time ago.

Comment: @JamesWestgate "They did it in Superman 3"

Answer (score 44):

Another easy way is to use ToString with a parameter.
Example:

```
float d = 54.9700F;    
string s = d.ToString("N2");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Result:

```
54.97
```

Answer (score 32):

You should use

```
inputvalue=Math.Round(inputValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

[Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)

> Math.Round rounds a double-precision floating-point value to a
>   specified number of fractional digits.

[MidpointRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx)

> Specifies how mathematical rounding methods should process a number
>   that is midway between two numbers.

Basically the function above will take your inputvalue and round it to 2 (or whichever number you specify) decimal places. With `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` when a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the **nearest number that is away from zero.** There is also another option you can use that rounds towards the **nearest even number.**

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 30):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)

```
value = Math.Round(48.485, 2);
```

Comment: Beat me to it (although I'd add a semi-colon on there, too ;) )

Comment: However, be careful with MidpointRounding: "If the value of the first digit in value  to the right of the digits decimal position is 5, the digit in the digits position is rounded up if it is odd, or left unchanged if it is even"

Answer (score 22):

you can try one from below.there are many way for this.

```
1. 
 value=Math.Round(123.4567, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) //"123.46"
2.
 inputvalue=Math.Round(123.4567, 2)  //"123.46"
3. 
 String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
4. 
string.Format("{0:F2}", 123.456789);     //123.46
string.Format("{0:F3}", 123.456789);     //123.457
string.Format("{0:F4}", 123.456789);     //123.4568
```

Comment: I used the fourth option. Writing F6 worked for me better than writing down 6 zeroes ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Use an interpolated string, this generates a rounded up string:

```
var strlen = 6;
$"{48.485:F2}"
```

Output

```
"48.49"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all these answers are missing the question.  The problem was to "Round UP", not just "Round".  It is my understanding that Round Up means that ANY fractional value about a whole digit rounds up to the next WHOLE digit.  ie:  48.0000000 = 48 but 25.00001 = 26.  Is this not the definition of rounding up?  (or have my past 60 years in accounting been misplaced?

Comment: You're right, but it's not an answer unless you say how to do that.