# how to output shrot number in double datatape ( C#.Net )

Tags: c#, int, double

I have Double `value = 65.536584144`

When I run The program ( Windows Form app ) ...

It show me the FULL number , Like this `( 65.536584144 )`

But I want only two numbers after point , Like this ( `65.53` )

How can I do it ?

There is a Function in C#.Net solve this problem ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357855/round-double-in-two-decimal-places-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       double number = 65.536584144;
       var newNumber = Math.Round(number , 2);
```