# How to round values of double type in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am wondering how to round `Datatable` values of double type to two decimals, I tried below ways but both of them didn't work for me, am I doing something wrong?

```
{ DataRow newRow = informationTable.NewRow();
                string typeColumn = material.Name.Replace(',', ':');// store element Id value             
                double gvolColumn = quantity.GrossVolume;// store gross volume value             
                double nvolColumn = quantity.NetVolume;// store net`enter code here` volume value             
                double gareaColumn = quantity.GrossArea;// store gross area value             
                double nareaColumn = quantity.NetArea;// store net area value             

                String.Format("{0:0.00}", gvolColumn);
                String.Format("{0:0.00}", nvolColumn);
                String.Format("{0:0.00}", gareaColumn);
                Math.Round(nareaColumn, 2);

  // set the relative information of current element into the table.

                newRow["Element Type"] = typeColumn;
                newRow["Gross volume"] = gvolColumn;
                newRow["Net volume"] = nvolColumn;
                newRow["Gross area"] = gareaColumn;
                newRow["Net area"] = nareaColumn;
                informationTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round double in two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357855/round-double-in-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Do you want to round or simply display a truncated value?

Comment: Yes, just to simply display maybe @Nikolaus

Comment: I checked out that solution but didn't work for me @HaveSpacesuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the value to a variable:

```
   nareaColumn = Math.Round(nareaColumn, 2);
```