# How to round to the nearest thousandth using C#

Tags: c#

I am an extreme beginner when it comes to coding, and I am building a batting average calculator as one of my first programs.

`Console.WriteLine("Your batting average is: " + (hits / atBats) );`

The input for hits is 165 and 419 for atBats, and it calculates to .3937947494. Though this is correct, I would like the number to read as .394. How would I do that?

Comment: .ToString("0.000");

Comment: Also, if you needed with additional calculations, look into Math.Round( equationOrFormula, DigitsToRoundTo )

Comment: @crtobin34 What is datatype of your variables hits and atBats? Is it int or double?

Comment: @noobprogrammer if they were integers you would have integer division and not get .393 as a result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round double in two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357855/round-double-in-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

A sample example that demonstrates usage of Math.Round() function:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
public static void Main (string[] args) {
    double result =  0.3937947494;

    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(result,3));
 }
}

// here result is = 0.3937947494, but you will get output as 0.394 in the console.
```

**VERSION 2**:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int hits = 165;
        int atBats = 419;
        double result = (double)hits / (double)atBats;
        Console.WriteLine("Your batting average is: " +Math.Round(result,3));
    }
}
// this produces the same result
// Your batting average is: 0.394
```

Screenshot for second alternative:

[image]

**VERSION 3:** Serves better readability (as suggested correctly by @Manti_Core

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double hits = 165;
        double atBats = 419;
        double result = hits/atBats;
        Console.WriteLine("Your batting average is: " + (hits / atBats).ToString("0.000"));
    }
}
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: boxing vs string formatting, wonder which is readable and quicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Format`:

```
var number = 0.3937947494;            
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.000}", number));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple like below :

```
double hits = 165;
double atBats = 419;
Console.WriteLine("Your batting average is: " + (hits / atBats).ToString("#.000"));
Console.Read();
```

here your are simply formatting the value that you want to display.

Performance of string format vs boxing values :

String format
[image: String format performance]

Boxing values
[image]

Comment: OP has not mentioned whether hits and atBats are int or double. Looking at the variables hits suggests that it cannot be decimal.. It has to be int. (Because Batting hits cannot be measured in decimal)

Comment: but OP has not mentioned the data type.. How about considering the memory optimization? You are using double for something which is not double... It seems that it is int. Since int takes 2 or 4 bytes compared to double which takes 8 bytes choosing correct datatype also plays an important role. You are wasting 4 bytes taking an integer value as double which is certainly not expected. But I am not denying your Readability issue that is lacking in my answer.

Comment: @noobprogrammer if OP has not mentioned int or double then i guess it is upto to the us to decide on it, because dividing by ints wont give you the result value like .3937947494 as OP mentions, i guess this partially depends on common sense ?

Comment: I agree to your point. But taking wrong datatype unnecessarily won't serve the purpose. We need to think from memory perspective as well... I am changing my answer to include the string formatting as well. Now it's upto OP which one to use :D

Comment: @noobprogrammer string formatting is already suggested twice in this thread as an answer.