# Round doubles operations

Tags: c#, double, rounding

Suppose I have three doubles, a, b and c.

```
double a = 1.234560123;
double b = 7.890120123;

double c = a * b;

c = 9.740827669535655129
```

I want to work with numbers with only 5 decimal places. So if I round a and b using Math.Round(a, 5) and Math.Round(b, 5) I get:

```
double a_r = Math.Round(a, 5);
double b_r = Math.Round(b, 5);

a_r = 1.23456
b_r = 7.89012

double c_r = a_r * b_r;

c_r = 9.7408265472
```

But when I calculate c, I still get a number with more than 5 decimal places (this will happen in every multiplication, division, potentiation and similar operations). I could round all results in my code, but that's hard work that I want to avoid.

As I use c in other operations and the results of this operations in other ones, I don't want to round all the intermediate results every time to not propagate the error caused by undesired decimal places.

Is there a way to define doubles with a fixed number of decimal places, independently of the operation?

Comment: The answer Reed gave you below was easily found via a Google search :)

Comment: Why would you want to limit your accuracy like that? Only wanting to display a certain number of decimal places is quite common, but I can't think of a reason to artificially limit the number of decimal places you use in calculating.

Comment: @anaximander This is especially true given he's using constants that have more precision than that...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Indeed. @GuilhermeCampos, as a general rule, when doing any sort of calculation in code you should work at the higher level of accuracy for as long as you can, and only cut down to your desired number of decimal places (or significant figures, or whatever) at the latest point you can get away with. Often, this is when you pass the value to the display, or when you're forced to assign it to something that only takes a certain type, like when you pass it to a method that only takes `int` or something.

Comment: Actually when you deal with engineering (or physics) problems that involve measured value you CAN'T work with decimal places bigger than your measured instrumed precision.
So, that undesired (and totally uncertain) decimal places could not be used to make other operation. The error they produce cause invalid results.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos That's technically only true of the initial inputs; as an engineer myself I've run the error propagation calculations - truncating your numbers at every stage increases the drift in your calculation. Start by taking the correct number of places for your instruments' precision, then run the calculation leaving the numbers intact, even when they gain more decimal places, and then display to your precision level (or one place less, sometimes) at the end. For added clarity, calculate your margin of error as it propagates through your calculation and display that too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem using Operator Overload.

So I re-defined all my operations as multiplication, division, complex multiplication and matrices operations to round the result to the number of decimal places I wanted.

An example:

```
public static double operator *(double d1, double d2)
{
    double result;
    result = Math.Round(d1 * d2, 5);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically, it's best to leave the doubles in place, and use the custom formatting to *display* the values to 5 decimal points:

```
double a = 1.234560123;
double b = 7.890120123;

double c = a * b;

Console.WriteLine("Result = {0:N5}", c);
```

Nearly all routines that convert numeric values into strings allow the use of the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) as well as [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that I use c to make others and others operations and I don't want to propagate the difference in results caused by the less important decimal places.

I don't want to do a Round or something like that for ever intermediate result I get.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos You can Round, but the precision of a double is rarely exact.  You're better off leaving that precision in place, then formatting the output at the end.  For details, see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

You can´t define a double with limited decimal places. You should rely on formatting the number when you display it. See  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303256/set-the-number-of-digits-after-the-point-in-double)